# Migrating SQL Server Group By Summary query to MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm currently adding MongoDB support to my application by adding a MongoDB repository that I can inject instead of the MS SQL Server repository. All is going well so far as most of the queries are simple and the database structure migrates nicely (it's fairly simple).

I have a couple of summary reports that I'm fighting at the moment that are relatively simple to achieve with SQL Server:

So I have a table (simplified for clarity), say:

```
[  Runners  ]
[RunnerId int]
[DateRun DateTime]
[RaceTime float]
```

Now I want a summary that contains a list of all the runners and the time of their last race. Note the above table will have multiple entries for each runner.

In SQL this can be achieved with:

```
SELECT r.runnerId, r.DateRun, r.RaceTime
FROM (
    SELECT runnerId, MAX(DateRun) AS lastRace
    FROM Runners GROUP BY runnerId
) AS x INNER JOIN runners AS r ON
    r.runnerId = x.runnerId AND 
    r.DateRun = x.lastRace
```

I'm using the official C# 10gen driver. Tips and pointers welcome.

Comment: This can be achieved with the aggregation framework

Comment: I agree with @alexjamesbrown, use the aggregation framework or MapReduce to achieve this.

Comment: If you post your actual document structure / couple of example docs, we might be able to help further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the comments indicated earlier, this can be achieved using the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).  I leave the C# to you, but I'll demonstrate a simple example using the Mongo shell.

Start with the following sample data.

```
> db.runners.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b3ec3c9dc68d628bd11869"), "name" : "a", "d" : ISODate("2012-10-29T00:00:00Z"), "time" : 10.3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b3ec429dc68d628bd1186a"), "name" : "a", "d" : ISODate("2012-10-20T00:00:00Z"), "time" : 12.3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b3ec549dc68d628bd1186b"), "name" : "b", "d" : ISODate("2012-10-29T00:00:00Z"), "time" : 11.45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b3ec5a9dc68d628bd1186c"), "name" : "b", "d" : ISODate("2012-10-25T00:00:00Z"), "time" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b3ec6a9dc68d628bd1186d"), "name" : "c", "d" : ISODate("2012-10-25T00:00:00Z"), "time" : 10.8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50b3f1249dc68d628bd1186e"), "name" : "b", "d" : ISODate("2012-11-13T00:00:00Z"), "time" : 23.2 }
```

Then, the following aggregation query returns:

```
> db.runners.aggregate({$sort:{name:1,d:-1}},{$group:{_id:"$name",d:{$first:"$d"},time:{$first:"$time"}}})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "c",
            "d" : ISODate("2012-10-25T00:00:00Z"),
            "time" : 10.8
        },
        {
            "_id" : "b",
            "d" : ISODate("2012-11-13T00:00:00Z"),
            "time" : 23.2
        },
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "d" : ISODate("2012-10-29T00:00:00Z"),
            "time" : 10.3
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

First, the [`$sort`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/sort/#_S_sort) operator sorts the `runners` by `name` and then `d` in descending order, so the first document per runner name should be the most recent run date for each runner.  Then, the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#_S_group) operator pulls the first document, along with the most recent run date and the runtime for that race, for each runner.

Comment: Thanks that does the job. The C# version is a little verbose with all the BsonDocuments here so I have to say that I'm looking forward to a Linq implementation for the aggregation framework to make queries like this a bit more intuitive to write and maintain.